# Java - Divide text into chunks of n-bytes

Tags: java, parsing

So I am kinda stuck on a program where I have to read a text file, using FileInputStream and divide that text into chunks of n-bytes. I have to issue one System.out.write(); call for each chunk, so I am wondering if there is a simple way to do this. Thanks!

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int size=0;

    FileInputStream fstream = null;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputFile = console.next();

    System.out.println("Chunk size?");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    size = in.nextInt();

    try {
        fstream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        System.out.println("Size in bytes : "
                + fstream.available());

        int content;

        while ((content = fstream.read()) != -1) {
            //System.out.write(); for every chunk of *size* bytes

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fstream != null)
                fstream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Just to clear things up, what I meant by issuing that write call was writing out each different chunk to the console.

Comment: Don't add a comment - edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use

   byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

   int byteCount;

   while((byteCount = fstream.read(bytes)) != -1)
       ...
2. you can simply create a string this way:

   new String(bytearray);

PS. sry for the missing codehighlighting, didn't work properly for some reason...