# Divide a Message(stored in Maps) into chunks in java

Tags: java

I have a java code to create a new message.

```
public boolean createNewMessage(Message m){
    if(decider.newMessage(m)){
        makeRoomForNewMessage(m.getSize());
        if(m.getSize()> 1024){
            //i need a code here
        }

        m.setTtl(this.msgTtl);
        addToMessages(m, true); 
        findConnectionsForNewMessage(m, getHost());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I want to put the condition that if the message size is greater than 1024, i.e 1MB, that split the message into chunks and each chunk size less than 1024.

Also the chunks have reference to the original message. For example, I have a message `M1` of size 1910. I want a code which split this message into chunks the chunks are referenced as `M11=1024` (M1's first chunk) and `M12=886`. (M1's second Chunk).

Any data structure approach which can do the above functionality?

Comment: we will not write you're code. try something yourself if that does not work, come back.

Comment: What is message. Could you just split it. With a String, I would use `message.substring(1024)` to get the beggining, and same method but different parameter to get the following text. You just need to try with this.

Comment: i do wrote some code but i got confused and didnt work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Divide text into chunks of n-bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135286/java-divide-text-into-chunks-of-n-bytes)

Comment: @SamCle88 this one use external file to split. but in my case all the data is stored and retrieved from maps and lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class DividedString of the kind

```
public class DividedString{
    private final String text;
    private final String[] dividedText;

    public DividedString (String text){
        this.text = text;
        // code where you split the text using substring, maybe
    }

    public String getChunk(int i){
        return dividedText[i];
    }

    // getter, setter, 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a map like this

```
Map<String, List<String>> messageChunks = new Hashmap<>();
```

where first string is your actual message and list of strings contains your message chunks in ordered sequence

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i have tied this one but i used Map instead of List. both works fine.
But one problem i am facing is that executes ones for a message.
i think i should try a loop on this one. let me try it than i will let you. 
and thanks for your help.